# Method calling twice on second run - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

What I'm doing: So, I'm using jQuery, Bootstrap and Font Awesome in this Web Page. This creates a text box for input, and when the user finishes writing their input and presses 'enter' the item is added to the checklist.

What's Wrong: When I add the first item to the check list, it works fine. But when I try to add the next one, it displays two input boxes, one in the right place, and one in the top left corner

```
/* Defining Variables */   
var toggled = false;
var thing = "";
var inMethod = false;

/* Defining Methods */
$(document).on("click", "#toggle", function() {
    if($(this).attr("class") == "fa fa-check-square-o fa-5x checked") {
        $(this).attr("class", "fa fa-square-o fa-5x unchecked");
    }
    else {
        $(this).attr("class", "fa fa-check-square-o fa-5x checked");
    }
    console.log();
});
function newThing() {
        $("body").html($("body").html() + "<div id='input'><div class='input-group margin-bottom-sm' id='imad'><span class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-file-text-o fa-1x'></i></span><input id='myInput' class='form-control' type='text' placeholder='Input'></div></div>");
        inMethod = true;
        console.log(inMethod);
        var box = $("#input");
        var ema = $("#imad");

        box.css("top", screen.height / 2 - 175);
        box.css("left", screen.width / 2 - 175);

        ema.css("top", screen.height / 64);
        ema.css("left", screen.width / 64);
}
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && inMethod) {
        thing = $("#myInput").val();
        $("#checklist").html( $("#checklist").html() + "<div id='checkOption'><i id='toggle' class='fa fa-square-o fa-5x unchecked'></i><span id='ds' class='fa fa-4x'>" + thing + "</span></div>" );
        window.location.hash = "";
        inMethod = false;
        console.log(inMethod);
        $("#input").remove();
    }
});
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    if(window.location.hash.substr(1) == "new") {
        inMethod = false;
        newThing();
    } else if(window.location.hash.substr(1) == "clear") {
        $("#checklist").html("");
    } else if(window.location.hash.substr(1) == "delete") {
        alert("Disabled for now");
    }
});
```

You can see an example of this working [here](http://www.okx.zz.mu/apKOEpo03).

Reproduce by:
1. Opening the dropdown menu
2. Click 'New',
3. Type something and press 'enter' then repeat step 1 and 2.

Comment: Anybody know the issue?

Comment: Can you put it on the JSFiddle? Just to see what it's exactly happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actualy copying the whole `<body>`, including scripts, which is why the events are multiplied.

Instead of:

```
$("body").html($("body").html() + "...
```

Use methods like [**`append`**](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$("body").append("...
```

While the above is also not a very good idea, I'd strongly suggest you to set a main container `<div id="container">` element inside `body` and modify your HTML inside, without affecitng javascript tags.

```
<body>

    <div id="container">
        All contents goes here
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // ...
        function newThing(){
            $("#container").append("...");
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.append()`. Right now, you're rendering the input box but the styling, by default, inserts the element at the top left of the page. Here's an updated plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/qrFOomKQrfZP3r4FmriC?p=preview